# need to know about the types of software i can use on MEEGO OS

Tags: meego

Can I use Windows software on Meego, or will I need to get a different set of software for a Meego netbook?

What kind of software is available for the Meego OS? I am looking forward to becoming a meego user.

Thank you very kindly.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot use Windows software on Meego. Meego is a Linux-based OS, so much Linux software should eventually become available. You can see some of the software in development at http://meego.gitorious.org/.

Also, Meego may have the capability to run many Android applications via an implementation of the Dalvik VM.